# grief vs grievances

Tags: differences

In a recent tweet of C. R Hills:

> The Serbian people will never set aside their *grief*, but I believe they are strong enough to set aside their *grievances*. The United States’ dedication to our partnership with Serbia is unwavering, as is our commitment to diplomacy.

Could someone please explain me the difference between grief & grievances?

Comment: I think this would be resolved simply by looking up the [two](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grief) [words](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grievance) in a dictionary.

Comment: *Grievance* did use to mean a thing causing sorrow, but this is marked as obsolete at least in M-W. So this is a clear case where the dictionary will explain.

Comment: looking up in a dic of course I did. but I'm a translator, therefore thinking in terms that are more than just dictionary.

Comment: Then you should say what the dictionary told you and what you still don't understand about it.

Answer (score 2):

#### Grief is an emotion, grievances are reasons to be angry

Grief is the emotion elicited by a severe loss, such as death of a close friend or family member.

In contrast, a grievance is a reason to be angry with someone. For example, they may have not paid enough attention to you, or not paid you enough salary, or stolen something from you.

If someone has killed your relative, you may have both grief and a grievance.

The article is arguing that you might come to a formal agreement to set aside mutual blame for destructive things that have happened in the past, but this does not mean that your adverse emotions must disappear.